# How to fix installation error by pybluez error on subprocess

Tags: python, windows, pybluez

I wanted to use pyBluez for Python, so I ran "pip install pybluez" (I use Win11 64gb)
but this error happened:

```
Collecting pybluez
  Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 4):

you can install the fresh release from github like so.
This worked for me.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez
```

"Python eggs are an older distribution format for Python. The new format is called a Python wheel[...] An egg file is basically a zip file with a different extension. Python can import directly from an egg."

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with my RHEL.
This helped me to overcome errors:

1. Enter `pip list` in terminal
2. Find the version of setuptools.
3. If setuptools version is more than 58, make it to less than 58 with the command `pip install setuptools==57.0.0`
4. After that I tried installing pyObex, which gave me again error related to Python.h not found.
5. Run the command to install libraries needed for python-dev as: `yum install python3-devel` (use apt-get if you are on Ubuntu or other distros)
6. Run this command to install Bluetooth package `yum install libbluetooth-dev`. (use apt-get if you are on Ubuntu or other distros)
7. If step 6 gives some error run this one instead `yum install bluez-libs-devel`
8. Now you are good to install `pip install PyOBEX`

Comment: Time travel to the distant past is always problematic. Unless you are truly stuck on dinosaur equipment which cannot be upgraded, probably don't try this.